# Pattern match on function result

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am trying to do match on function result 
on scala it will look like this

```
validate(number) match {
case true => "true"
case false => "false"
}
```

I am trying to do something similar in haskell

```
main = do    
    number <- getLine  
    res <- case (validate (read number::Int)) of 
        (True) -> "True"
        (False) -> "False"
    putStrLn res
```

Also I understand I can do with out the `do` notation, but not sure where to start.

Comment: "do" is syntactic sugar for *Monads*. The "real", underlying version is `main = getLine >>= \number -> case ...`. But you should first learn about *Functors* and *Applicative*. These are the search terms to get you started. Teaser: `main = (maybe "False" useTheValue . readMaybe) <$> getLine`

Comment: Thank it is definitely on the road map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell `read` throws an exception if there is a parse error.

But there is [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) which will return a Maybe value.

```
import Text.Read

main = do
  number <- getLine
  let res = case (readMaybe number :: Maybe Int) of
              Just x -> "True"
              Nothing -> "False"
  putStrLn res
```

Note the use of `let` instead of monadic bind operator `<-` since `readMaybe` is a pure function.

You might even be able to avoid the type hint if you use the parsed
value in a way which allows the compiler to infer its type, e.g.:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
  -- any list will do

main = do
  number <- getLine
  case readMaybe number of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "bad number"
    Just n  -> print (fibs !! n)
```

No type annotation is needed here because `!!` take an `Int` argument,
and so `n` must have type `Int`
which means `readMaybe number` must have type `Maybe Int`.

**Update**

Stylistically I would recommend that you use `let` here - using
bind is completely unnecessary as you are computing a pure value.

However, you can write this with the bind operator by using `return`:

```
main = do
  number <- getLine
  res <- return $ case (readMaybe number :: Maybe Int) of
                    Just _ -> "True"
                    Nothing -> "False"
  putStrLn res
```

Comment: This is very nice. however, this will still not work with the bind operator am i right?

Comment: Why do you want to use the bind operator? But if you feel you must, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I just didn't know how and what to use and when. Thank you very much for  your time!

Comment: IMO this is better without the `res <- return ...` section. If someone really really wants to use `<-` instead of `let`, it's better to explain why that's silly than it is to show how to do it.

Comment: I agree it's not the way I would prefer to write it, and I've updated that section a bit. I think a discussion of `let` vs. `... <- return ...` deserves it's own SO question. Out of curiosity I did a code search on Hackage and found a surprisingly large number of instances of  immediately binding a return value: http://lpaste.net/177514

Comment: Well - lpaste truncated that pastebin, so here's the full version: [__(link)__](https://gist.github.com/erantapaa/cbf816c28d4b8fe5da93deb4988300ec)